# DataSource configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

How to optimize setting data source fields when working with multiple datasources?

```
@Bean(name = ["dataSource"])
    fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        val dataSource = DriverManagerDataSource()
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName)
        dataSource.url = url
        dataSource.username = username
        dataSource.password = password
        return dataSource
    }
```

Reduce boiler plate code shown above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible via application.yaml file and little DSL configuration.
***application.yaml:***

```
spring:
  datasource:
    first:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      password: #{DB_FIRST_PASSWORD}#
      username: #{DB_FIRST_USERNAME}#
      url: jdbc:mysql://#{DB_FIRST_HOST}#:#{DB_FIRST_PORT}#/#{DB_FIRST_NAME}#
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: 5
        minimum-idle: 5
    second:
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      password: #{DB_SECOND_PASSWORD}#
      username: #{DB_SECOND_USERNAME}#
      url: jdbc:postgresql://#{DB_SECOND_HOST}#:#{DB_SECOND_PORT}#/#{DB_SECOND_NAME}#
      hikari:
        maximum-pool-size: 3
        minimum-idle: 3
```

***DatasourceConfiguration*** class

```
@Configuration
class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @get:Bean
    @get:ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.first")
    val firstDataSourceProperties = DataSourceProperties()

    @get:Bean
    @get:ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.second")
    val secondDataSourceProperties = DataSourceProperties()

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.second.hikari") // GETS HIKARI CONFIGURATION
    fun firstDataSource(): DataSource =
        primaryDataSourceProperties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .build()

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.second.hikari") // GETS HIKARI CONFIGURATION
    fun secondDataSource(): DataSource =
        deliveryDataSourceProperties
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .build()
```

In addition, you can specify DataSource Hikari configuration using ***@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.first.hikari")*** annotation

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = [REPOSITORY_BASE_PATH + PRIMARY],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager"
)
class PrimaryJpaConfiguration {

    @get:Bean
    @get:Primary
    @get:ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa")
    val jpaProperties = JpaProperties()

    @get:Bean
    @get:Primary
    @get:ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa.hibernate")
    val hibernateProperties = HibernateProperties()

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun primaryEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") datasource: DataSource,
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = builder

        /**   SETTING APPROPRIATE DATASOURCE   **/
        .dataSource(datasource)

        /**   SETTING ENTITIES LOCATION   **/
        .packages(ENTITY_BASE_PATH + PRIMARY)

        /**    SETTING HIBERNATE PROPERTIES FROM ACTIVE .YAML/.YML FILE      **/
        .properties(hibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(jpaProperties.properties, HibernateSettings()))
        .build()

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun primaryTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") factory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    ) = factory.`object`?.let { JpaTransactionManager(it) }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = [REPOSITORY_BASE_PATH + SECONDARY],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager"
)
class SecondaryJpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun secondaryEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") datasource: DataSource,
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = builder
        .dataSource(datasource)
        .packages(ENTITY_BASE_PATH + SECONDARY)
        .build()

    @Bean
    fun secondaryTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("secondaryEntityManagerFactory") factory: LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
    ) = factory.`object`?.let { JpaTransactionManager(it) }
}
```